# EclipseFP doesn't working

Tags: eclipse, haskell, functional-programming, eclipse-fp

I am trying to install EclipseFP on Eclipse version: Mars Release (4.5.0) on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5.

While Haskell perspective is appeared, nothing special for Haskell language is not working (Syntax highlight, hoogle search & etc...)

[image: Syntax highlight]
[image: Hoogle Search]

Here is my Eclipse Preferences: 
[image: Eclipse preferences]

And it seems that problem is that not all necessary packages could be compiled (But sure that this is the root cause)

For example, when I am pressing button "Install from Hackage" in the Haskell helper executables it is trying to compile it but fails because of `ghc-pkg-lib-0.3`:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/.eclipsefp/sandbox
Configuring ghc-pkg-lib-0.3...
Building ghc-pkg-lib-0.3...
Failed to install ghc-pkg-lib-0.3
Build log ( /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/.eclipsefp/sandbox/logs/ghc-pkg-lib-0.3.log ):
Configuring ghc-pkg-lib-0.3...
Building ghc-pkg-lib-0.3...
Preprocessing library ghc-pkg-lib-0.3...
[1 of 1] Compiling Language.Haskell.Packages ( src/Language/Haskell/Packages.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-b2e886dd/build/Language/Haskell/Packages.o )

src/Language/Haskell/Packages.hs:170:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
                   with ‘Distribution.ModuleName.ModuleName’
    Expected type: InstalledPackageInfo_
                     Distribution.ModuleName.ModuleName
      Actual type: InstalledPackageInfoString
    In the expression: pkgconf
    In the expression:
      pkgconf {exposedModules = convert e, hiddenModules = convert h}

src/Language/Haskell/Packages.hs:170:47:
    Couldn't match type ‘ExposedModule’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: [ExposedModule]
    In the first argument of ‘convert’, namely ‘e’
    In the ‘exposedModules’ field of a record

src/Language/Haskell/Packages.hs:171:39:
    Couldn't match type ‘ExposedModule’
                   with ‘Distribution.ModuleName.ModuleName’
    Expected type: [Distribution.ModuleName.ModuleName]
      Actual type: [ExposedModule]
    In the ‘hiddenModules’ field of a record
    In the expression:
      pkgconf {exposedModules = convert e, hiddenModules = convert h}
cabal.real: Error: some packages failed to install:
buildwrapper-0.9.1 depends on ghc-pkg-lib-0.3 which failed to install.
ghc-pkg-lib-0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Its not what you asked for, but have you tried leksah? Its a native Haskell IDE.

Comment: It seems that `ghc-pkg-lib` doesn't specify upper bounds for its dependencies, and you are getting a newer version of `Cabal` than it can successfully build with. Consider adding an explicit constraint like `Cabal <= 1.19` to your install line manually (you can see from the [Hackage build logs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-pkg-lib-0.3/reports/1) that it has successfully built with `Cabal-1.18.1.3`); and do send a note/smack to the package maintainer.

Comment: Have found updated version of Package.hs on Github, and build this module successfully, but broken in next module... Also found mention on github that EclipseFP is no longer maintained...

Comment: And yes, i've installed Leksah, but seems that it has less features...

Comment: As a previous eclipsefp user, i now switch to emacs ,which may have the best support for haskell presently with various plugins to autocomplete,give type hints etc..

Comment: @DanielWagner Any idea how to do change the command line EclipseFP uses?  The problem is that it attempts to install buildwrapper in a private sandbox automatically, and doesn't seem to provide any options that I can see for changing the versions of components it downloads... note that ghc-pkg-lib seems to have been updated, but the same error also appears in buildwrapper-0.9.1.

Comment: EclipseFP is no longer maintained or supported: http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.fr/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of frequently changes happens in EclipseFP and BuildWrapper, they have stopped supporting these 2 project and should use some Leskah too have an IDE
http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.com.tr/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html